# Conversion between feet and meters

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("This program converts between feet and meters");
    System.out.printf("%5s%12s%6s%12s%12s\n","Feet","Meters","|","Meters","Feet");
    System.out.println("                                                    ");

    for(double f = 1.0, m = 20; f <= 10.0; f++, m += 5.0){
        System.out.printf("%5.1f%12.3f%6s%12,1f%12.3f\n", f, footToMeter(f), "|", m, meterToFoot(m));
    }

}
public static double footToMeter(double foot){
    return foot * 0.3048;
}
public static double meterToFoot(double meter){
    return meter / 0.3048;
}
```

Results should be like:

```
Feet Meters | Meters Feet
1.0  0.305  | 20.0   65.574
2.0  0.610  | 25.0   81.967
```

But instead I get the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '1'
at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2503)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2467)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2414)
at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:920)
at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:821)
at Ex6_9.main(Ex6_9.java:15)
```

Comment: But the results actually are like?

Comment: when i run the code it gives me errors i don't know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the errors? See the [help/on-topic] about writing a good question so we can answer it better (and quicker).

Comment: I get this error:                                                     This program converts between feet and meters
 Feet      Meters     |      Meters        Feet
                                                    
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '1'
 at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2503)
 at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2467)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2414)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:920)
 at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:821)
 at Ex6_9.main(Ex6_9.java:15)

Comment: You should edit the question with the error information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in this line

```
System.out.printf("%5.1f%12.3f%6s%12,1f%12.3f\n", f, footToMeter(f), "|", m, meterToFoot(m));
```

Specifically, `"%5.1f%12.3f%6s%12,1f%12.3f\n"` needs to be changed to `"%5.1f%12.3f%6s%12.1f%12.3f\n"`. Note the comma was changed to a period.

Comment: thanks a lot David.  a comma is going to put me in trouble here now.  thanks a lot